# Haproxy failing to start after VM move (Debian 8 [systemd])

Tags: debian, haproxy, systemd

We are running HAProxy 1.6.1 on Debian 8 virtual machines.  I was moving our 2 instances to a different size VM, however, when I rebooted they did not come back up.

I can't even run the haproxy binary file.  Here's what I get when I try:

```
  ./haproxy
  Illegal Instruction

  sudo ./haproxy
  [no output]

  ./haproxy -v
  Illegal Instruction

  sudo/haproxy -v
  [no output]
```

Same thing if I try to check the config with -c -f (though I don't think this is a config issue).

Here's what I have in kern.log:

```
  Mar  7 11:41:41 rproxyws1 kernel: traps: haproxy[4031] trap invalid opcode ip:4843a0 sp:7fff51856ac8 error:0 in haproxy[400000+cf000]
```

One thing that does seem to have happened is a kernel update during the move (from 4.1.5 to 4.4.0), but I've manually renerted to the old kernel, but the new problems remain.

Does anyone have any ideas!? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the fact that I used the CPU=native option in my original compilation.  Apparently this is a bad idea for virtualised environments as I can break.  I should have read [the manual](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy-1.5) more carefully:

```
You may also choose your CPU to benefit from some optimizations. This is
particularly important on UltraSparc machines. For this, you can assign
one of the following choices to the CPU variable :

  - i686 for intel PentiumPro, Pentium 2 and above, AMD Athlon
  - i586 for intel Pentium, AMD K6, VIA C3.
  - ultrasparc : Sun UltraSparc I/II/III/IV processor
  - **native : use the build machine's specific processor optimizations. Use with
    extreme care, and never in virtualized environments (known to break).**
  - generic : any other processor or no CPU-specific optimization. (default)
```

Recompiling with CPU=generic fixed it.

Comment: I confirm this. Resolved with the proposed change.

Answer (score 1):

How have you moved to the other two instances?

I guess you must have installed haproxy and copied the haproxy.cfg file in the new two instances.Please check that the user haproxy(service useron OS) is present there?

Check haproxy status and also try to run command without ./.

If you have compiled from source please verify these settings with your previous ubuntu machines.The symopsis are like this;

Build options :
  TARGET  = linux2628

CPU     = native

CC      = gcc

CFLAGS  = -O2 -march=native -g -fno-strict-aliasing

OPTIONS = USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_STATIC_PCRE=1

Comment: Hi umar, thanks for your help . To clarify these were simply VM resizes, so although the VMs were moved to a different host, the instances remain exactly the same (users etc).  (Also not running ubuntu, but debian).  I'm going to try recompiling.

Comment: The problem turned out to be that I had used CPU=native in my previous compilation.  Apparently this is not recommended for virtualised environments, as it is likely to break.